# What is an inner bath tub panel for?

Tags: bathtub

I removed a Moldy wooden bath tub panel and right after it there is another panel which feels like hard foam.

Sorry I do not have pictures.

Do you have any idea what material this is and what purpose this panel serves?  It is an old building I don’t think modern baths have these second panels.

What material is it and would it have to be discarded if it affected by mold?

Thanks.

Comment: Insulation I suspect

Comment: I have seen some tub installations where insulation was either sprayed onto the tub itself or was installed around the tub.  I think you may have the latter.

Comment: Only things that come to mind are actual insulation foam, or not being familiar with cement board (since you said "hard" foam I could imagine that as a description of cement board by someone who wasn't familiar with the product.)

Comment: So, take a picture or two then - it may help us....

Comment: Where are we talking above or below the tub?